# Emails being sent to strange addresses

Tags: email

I use Yahoo Mail from Android devices. In my Sent box over the last few weeks I see a handful of completely blank e-mails (no subject and no contents) being sent to very strange addresses such as: `return-a1756-676244-676247-ba1aedb9=136622015=8u@dha.biznes1.com`

Other addresses include `...@snip.prikn.com`, `...@tej.ruhour1.com` and `...@gsh.hirareth.com`.

All of these addresses (i.e., the `...` in the above) start with the string `return-` and are followed by a very large random-looking string/number.

I haven't knowingly shared my login information with anyone.

What could it be?

Comment: My first guess is that it's mailto: unsubscribe actions, read receipts, calendar responses, or other ~automated email transactions you might have engaged in.

Answer (score 3):

I would venture a couple of hypothesis:

1. They are mailing list unsubscribes handled automatically by Yahoo when you mark certain emails as spam. I know that Gmail does check for "unsubscribe" headers when you do that and lets you use them or not. Not sure about Yahoo. But that would make sense with the return-... Did you mark messages as spam or unsubscribe from things ?
2. They are read receipts or similar signalling. The webmail doesn't honor read receipts but if you have an app reading your email with an IMAP interface, it might be triggering it.

Either way, to find out more about this, you should view the original sent email with all its headers and show us. You should obviously redact everything that looks like an ID number but this would probably give us a better clue about what is happening.